# validation of fields in a form in scala with lift frame work

Tags: forms, validation, scala, lift

I am working with the Lift framework and Scala. I have a form to sign up to my application, and I want to validate all the fields in it. I have a snippet where I access my form values, and one validation class where I wrote my validation functions. The following code is what I've tried so far. In my Snippet:

```
if(validationClassObject.validateName(first_name)){
  if(validationClassObject.validateName(last_name)){
    if(validationClassObject.validateEmail(email)){
      if(validationClassObject.validateUserName(name)){

        // Adding values to the DB
        S.redirectTo("/")

      }
      else{
        S.notice("Invalid User Name")
      }               
    }
    else{
      S.notice("Invalid Mail Id")                 
    }
  }
  else{
    S.notice("Invalid Last name")
  }           
}
else{
  S.notice("Invalid First Name")
}
```

In the `validationClass` I wrote the validation code looks like:

```
//function for validating mail address
 def validateEmail(email: String): Boolean =
     """(\w+)@([\w\.]+)""".r.unapplySeq(email).isDefined
 //code for validating remaining fileds like above
```

This is working, but I know this is not the best way of coding this operation in Scala. How could I modify my code in a more scalable way? How can I use case classes here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  do:

```
  def av[T,V](validationFunction: => Boolean, error: => T)(f: => V)={
    if(!validationFunction) error
     else f
  }
  def v[V](validationFunction: => Boolean, error: => String)(f: => V)=av(validationFunction,S.notice(error))(f)


  import validationCalssObject._

  v(validateName(last_name),"Invalid Last name"){v(validateName(name),"Invalid User Name"){...}}
```

`av` is a abstract method with `T` and `V` as result types for the `error` function and continue function `f`. `v` is the more specific function what expects a string for `error` and encapsulates the `notice()` call. we give `f` as the part in the curly braces `v(validation, errormsg){/*todo when there is no problem*/}`.

Comment: can you please explain me that why we have to use def `av[T,V]` and `v[V]` here. and i couldn't understand the `v()` function calling part too because we are not passing the second parameter `(f: => V)` to it i guess. can u plz explain. thanx @axaluss.

Answer (score 1):

I can't do formatting in comments so I'll post a new answer.

```
def badName() = if ("name" == "") Some("bad name") else None

def badEmail() = if ("email" == "") Some("bad email") else None

val verifications = List[() => Option[String]](badName, badEmail)

val failed = verifications.flatMap(_())
if (failed.nonEmpty) {
    // handle failed
} else {
    // your custom logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (badName) S.notice
else if (badEmail) S.notice
else if (badDay) S.notice
else { // everything OK...
    // return a JsCmd or what else do you wanted here
}
```

An alternative solution can be written using Option and flatMap, without these all "if"-s hardcoded. If you're interested in that -- ask..